# Shell to .bat script

Tags: batch-file

I'm converting a shell script that works into a .bat file.

Does anyone know how I would approach getting a version number from a file:

```
VERSION="$(<dist/public/VERSION)"
echo "Version: ${VERSION}"
```

This does not work:

```
set VERSION=dist\public\VERSION
echo "Version: %{VERSION}"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct syntax would be:

```
set /p VERSION=<dist\public\VERSION
echo Version: %VERSION%
```